# How to restart Linux from inside a C++ program?

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, reboot, suid

I have a Qt 4 GUI where I need to have a option in a drop-down menu that allows the user to choose to restart the computer. I realize this might seem redunant with the ability to restart the computer in other ways, but the choice needs to stay there. I've tried using system() to call the following:

1. a suid-root shell script
2. a non-suid shell script
3. a suid-root binary program

and all of them just cause

```
reboot: must be superuser
```

to be printed. Using system() to call reboot directly does the same thing. I'm not especially attached to using system() to do this, but it seemed like the most direct choice.

How can I reboot the system from the GUI?

Comment: printf("Please push the reset button now");

Comment: Have you tried running it as a superuser?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this in Windows, but most are not intentional

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/24/9983984.aspx

Comment: This can be done within KDE apps. For instance, both KGet and KTorrent can told to turn off your computer when they've finished downloading. But I don't know if what they use to do that is KDE-specific or whether you can do it Qt without the KDE stuff.

Comment: FYI, Linux ignores the suid bit on scripts, since there is a serious security problem with allowing suid scripts. See section 5.5.3 here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking/puis/ch05_05.htm

Answer (score 20):

The `reboot` function is described in the [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html). Under **glibc**, you can pass the `RB_AUTOBOOT` macro constant to perform the reboot.

*Note that if `reboot` is not preceded by a call to `sync`, data may be lost.*

Using **glibc** in **Linux**:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>

sync();
reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
```

Answer (score 9):

In Linux:

```
#define LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF 0x4321fedc   

sync();
reboot(LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF);
```

Comment: If you're using the glibc version, #include <sys/reboot.h> should be included in the above code... if so, just use the #define RB_POWER_OFF in that header file...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried running a shell script, using gksudo? Something like

```
gksudo shutdown -r
```

With any luck, that should pull up a modal dialogue to get user credentials.

Comment: Well, you don't really need to run it as a shell script, just `execv` it, or if you really want the PATH functionality that comes along with shell scripts, `execvp`.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it on almost any linux system.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>

int main () {
  sync();
  setuid(0);
  reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);
  return(0);
}
```

Then just compile with `gcc reboot.c -o reboot` and do `chmod a+s reboot` on the binary.  Then call reboot as any user and the system should reboot smoothly.  The way you do this through your GUI varies, as in if your Desktop Environment was KDE for example, it's quite different than doing the same thing under Fluxbox.

Answer (score 1):

suid-ing shell scripts is just dangerous as already mentioned (which is why that didn't work).

I suspect that suid-ing the binary doesn't work because system spawns its subprocess with the user's actual uid and not the suid one, again for security reasons (it would let you substitute any binary for the one being called and run it as root).

You could put a copy of reboot in a location protected such that only users you want have permission to can execute it, and then suid-root THAT.

Alternately give them sudoer privilege to execute JUST the command you care about and system out to something like `"ksh -c 'sudo reboot'"`

Answer (score 0):

In binary try to call

```
setuid (0);
```

before system() call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this didn't work when the program was called from another program. It does work if a program is called directly from the command line though.

Answer (score 0):

how would you reboot the system from the command line on your system?

basically do

```
system( <however you wouuld do it from the command line> );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that's what we've tried, and it doesn't work.