# Shutdown Linux from C program meant to be ran as init process

Tags: c, power-management, init

I'm writing a C program to do various stuff on a Linux system, then shut it down. This program will be started with the command line option `init=/path/to/program` with PID 1, and because of that, I can't use `execl("/sbin/poweroff", "poweroff", NULL);`, because the `poweroff` command doesn't shutdown the system itself, it asks the process with PID 1 to do it. So what code does `init` use to shutdown the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Why doesn't `poweroff` work?

A number of programs assume the kernel has booted with `init` as PID 1. On many systems `init` is a symbolic link to the `systemd` program; similarly on these systems, `poweroff` is often a symbolic link to the `systemctl` program.

In your setup, `systemd` is never started since you set your custom `init=/path/to/program` kernel parameter line. This is why the `poweroff` command doesn't work: `systemctl` is trying to contact a `systemd` instance which was never created.

### How to power off without `systemd`.

The `reboot` function is described in the [Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html). Under **glibc**, you can pass the `RB_POWER_OFF` macro constant to perform the reboot.

*Note that if `reboot` is not preceded by a call to `sync`, data may be lost.*

Using **glibc** in **Linux**:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>

sync();
reboot(RB_POWER_OFF);
```

#### See also

> [How to restart Linux from inside a C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18766704/1806289)

Comment: Suggestion: also note that init is responsible for other pre-reboot tasks, like stopping daemons, unmounting (or at least remount read-only) all filesystems, shutting down LVM/RAID/etc., and so forth.